# username and password from csv instead of text file

Tags: python, csv, passwords

I have a text file to read and write usernames and passwords. I would like it to instead be on a csv to have ***1.*** Sorted charting ***2.*** Any words on the text file can be used for the username and password even if they are in separate lines, they can be used interchangeably, which was unintentional. I would like it to only use info from the correct row.
Such as `[apple, pear] [banana, orange]`. It should only accept it if apple and pear or banana and orange are together. This code works fine it is just running from a blank text file.

```
import time
import sys

text1 = input("\n Write username ")
text2 = input("\n Write password ")

saveFile = open('usernames+passwords', 'a')
saveFile.write(text1 + '    ' + text2 + '\n')

saveFile = open('usernames+passwords', 'r')
saveFile.seek(0)
uap = saveFile.read()

saveFile.close()

max_attempts = 3
attempts = 0

while True:
    print("Username")
    username = input("")

    print("Password")
    password = input("")

    if username in uap and password in uap:
        print("Access Granted")
    else:
        attempts+=1
        if attempts >= max_attempts:
            print(f"reached max attempts of {attempts} ")
            sys.exit()
        print("Try Again (10 sec)")
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    break
```

Comment: you don't need `seek(0)` after opening file.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with `csv`.

Comment: Using `seek(0)` fixed an issue i had so i kept it. I want a csv to store all usernames and passwords. I think csv's have a nicer way to format this and might solve my one big issue. I have a list of usernames and passwords in a text file. The problem is for a username i can use a password for a different username. If i enter a username of `test01` and the password is `test`, i am able to use this but i can also use a different password for the same username. Rendering the program almost useless.

Comment: `csv` is also `text file` but it use `comma` to seperate data in row, and `new line` to seperate rows with data. You can use your text file but you have to read it in different way. You use `read()` to you have all as single string but you should use `readlines()` to have every line as separated string - and then use `for`-loop to check if you have `password` and `user` in the same line. And frankly `csv` works in similar way - it reads all line as separated string (but it also convert this string to list).

Comment: BTW: if in your file you will write values using `comma` (`,`) instead of spaces `"   "` then you will have also `csv` file - `write(text1 + ',' + text2 + '\n')`

Comment: BTW: maybe you have to use `seek()` because you didn't close file after writing. Normally when you close and open again then it automatically set `seek(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problem is because you use `read()` and you get all as single string and later it check `password`, `username` in full string.

You should use `readline()` to get every line as separated string - and later you need `for`-loop to check `password`, `username` in every line separatelly.

```
# ... code ...

save_file = open('usernames+passwords', 'a')
save_file.write(text1 + '   ' + text2 + '\n')
save_file.close()

read_file = open('usernames+passwords', 'r')
all_lines = read_file.readlines()
read_file.close()

max_attempts = 3
attempts = 0

while True:
    print("Username")
    username = input("")

    print("Password")
    password = input("")
    
    found = False
    for line in all_lines:
        if username in line and password in line:
           found = True
           break  # no need to check other lines
        
    if found:
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    else:
        # ... code ...
```

but this gives access if you put `password` as `username` and `username` as `password`.

You would have to split every line to get list with `[password, username]` and next check it with indexex `[0]`,`[1]`, and use `==` instead of `in` to make sure that it not in some longer string - ie. `"abc" in "xabcy"` gives `True` but `"abc" == "xabcy"` gives `False`

```
# ... code ...

save_file = open('usernames+passwords', 'a')
save_file.write(text1 + '   ' + text2 + '\n')
save_file.close()

read_file = open('usernames+passwords', 'r')
all_lines = read_file.readlines()
all_lines = [line.strip().split('   ') for line in all_lines]  # split values in lines
read_file.close()

max_attempts = 3
attempts = 0

while True:
   print("Username")
   username = input("")

   print("Password")
   password = input("")
   
   found = False
   for line in all_lines:
       if username == line[0] and password == line[0]:  # use indexes `[0]`, `[1]`
          found = True
          break  # no need to check other lines
       
   if found:
       print("Access Granted")
       break
   else:
       # ... code ...
```

Of course this way you almost have `csv` file - but with `'   '` instead of `,` as separator. But it can be safer to use `csv` module for this. But as I remeber it can't use multichar separator so you will have to delete `usernames+passwords` and create it again with new code - or you will have to manually replace in file separator `'   '` with `,`

```
import csv

# ... code ...

save_file = open('usernames+passwords', 'a')
cvs_writer = csv.writer(save_file)
cvs_writer.writerow( [text1 , text2] )
save_file.close()

read_file = open('usernames+passwords', 'r')
cvs_reader = csv.reader(read_file)
all_lines = list(cvs_reader)
read_file.close()

max_attempts = 3
attempts = 0

while True:
    print("Username")
    username = input("")

    print("Password")
    password = input("")
    
    found = False
    for line in all_lines:
        if username == line[0] and password == line[1]:
           found = True
           break
        
    if found:
        print("Access Granted")
        break
    else:
        # ... code ...
```